# Provide localization from custom Laravel packages

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php, package-development

I struggle on how to use localizations correctly with custom packages for laravel?
`$this->loadTranslationsFrom(__DIR__ . '/../../resources/lang', 'package_lang');` does not provide me access to my nested translation-files in my views (Blade Templating).

My Folder-Structure

```
foo-package/
├── resources/
│   ├── lang/
│   │   ├── de/
│   │   │   └── subs/
│   │   │       ├── fields.php
│   │   │       └── general.php
│   │   └── en/
│   │       └── subs/
│   │           ├── fields.php
│   │           └── general.php
│   └── views/
│           └── subs/
│               ├── create.php
│               └── edit.php
└── src/
    └── Providers/
        └── PackageProvider.php
```

In my views I try to access it like this:

```
<label>{{ __('package_lang::subs/fields.name_of_subs') }}</label>
```

or

```
<button type="submit">{{ __('package_lang::subs/fields.create_sub') }}</button>
```

Resulting in returning the translation string key.

The ServiceProvider is loaded in my `app.php`config, in which I have set the correct locale as well (Debug-Bar proves that). Tried `composer dump-autoload`, but no success.
I'm only getting this to work if I use the standard project folders of laravel `project/resources/lang`, which prevents me from using my prefered namespace `package_lang::` and making my package ready for localization.

**My Service Provider**

```
namespace FooPackage\Providers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class PackageServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__ . '/../../database/migrations');
        $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/../../resources/views', 'package_views');
        $this->loadTranslationsFrom(__DIR__.'/../../resources/lang', 'package_lang');
    }
}
```

Any idea how to solve it?

EDIT:

I have multiple packages following this folder structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay nevermind, the Post was missing out one major point.
Multiple custom packages are involved, which uses the same namespace `package_lang`, which causes the problem.

For whatever reason, the second namespace-parameter of `$this->loadTranslationsFrom(__DIR__ . '/../../resources/lang', 'package_lang');` has to be uniquely defined!
Changing this solves the problem.

Just a side note:
The above rule does however not apply to `$this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/../../resources/views', 'package_views');` where multiple packages can have the same namespace.

Comment: @MrMAG can you confirm that this works for validation.php too? I'm not able to get the translated messages on validating requests. It just ignores the validation language lines within this file.